# Is a French PAC skydiving license equivalent to an AFF license?

Tags: parachute, skydiving

I am planning to do a skydiving course and I was thinking of doing the course in France. That means, I would get a stage PAC license course instead of AFF. I want to know how PAC is different from AFF (previously I have only heard of AFF) and can I use the PAC license to skydive anywhere in the world?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean you are learning to skydive and will be taking PAC instead of AFF, then the differences are minor. IIRC, in PAC the last jump is number 8, whereas in AFF and PFF it's jump 7.

There's also the Canadian version, PFF, and I assume other variations as well. Generally, schools do not follow any of these exactly and add their own variations.

Comment: Does it has any difference on where all it is accepted? Is it accepted everywhere in the world if I want to go solo sky diving?

Comment: Like any *permit*, a AFF/PFF/PAC is not international. However, like most *licenses*, your A-license is. So I would recommend immediately applying for your A-license once you have the 25 jumps. That said, a completed PAC/PFF/AFF along with your logbook is 99% likely going to allow you to jump anywhere in the world, although they may demand a check jump if you have just finished the program.